# ¿Cómo imputar los NA con el valor válido más cercano?

Tags: r

Imaginemos un vector como el siguiente:

```
x <- c(NA,1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,4)
```

La idea sería completar cada `NA` por cualquier valor válido, eligiendo siempre el que sea más cercano (en cualquier dirección). Con este ejemplo, el vector esperado sería:

```
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción menos creativa es usar la función `fill()` de `tidyr`.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, NA), 
                 col2 = c("a", NA, NA, "d", "e", "d"))

tidyr::fill(df, col1)    
tidyr::fill(df, col2)    
tidyr::fill(df, col1, col2)
```

Recibe un data.frame y se puede seleccionar sobre qué columnas opera y la dirección de la que tomará el valor válido,incluyendo arriba, abajo o alternando.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una excelente implementación para este problema, en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10081991/6836377). La función (simplemente modifiqué el nombre) sería:

```
impute_na_from_nn_value <- function(dat) {

  N <- length(dat)
  na.pos <- which(is.na(dat))
  if (length(na.pos) %in% c(0, N)) {
    return(dat)
  }
  non.na.pos <- which(!is.na(dat))
  intervals  <- findInterval(na.pos, non.na.pos,
                             all.inside = TRUE)
  left.pos   <- non.na.pos[pmax(1, intervals)]
  right.pos  <- non.na.pos[pmin(N, intervals+1)]
  left.dist  <- na.pos - left.pos
  right.dist <- right.pos - na.pos

  dat[na.pos] <- ifelse(left.dist <= right.dist,
                        dat[left.pos], dat[right.pos])
  return(dat)
}
```

La idea es pasar el vector a corregir, por ejemplo:

```
x <- c(1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,4)
rbind(x, impute_na_from_nn_value(x))

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
x   NA    1    2   NA    3   NA   NA    4
     1    1    2    2    3    3    4    4
```